# Approaches to Apply Incremental Row Changes Based on a RAW table?

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns

I have inherited a collection of data that is divided into two parts: A master record file and many incremental update files. These records are saved in a single table.
I have two primary requirements:

1. I would like to properly update my database model to have an active table tracked as a temporal table.
2. I would like to start with my master record data and then apply each incremental update file from the raw table in some defined order (a date received column).

Is there a method for doing this without a cursor, while loop, or SSIS job to load each file again? If such a way exists, I would basically configure my new temporal table and then merge each incremental file in my specified order. Any approaches to consider?

Edit for additional clarification:

Let's say I have the following raw table:

| Key Value | Update Flag | Sort Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | Add | 01/01/2000 |
| X1 | Change | 02/01/2000 |
| X1 | Change | 03/01/2000 |
| X1 | Change | 04/01/2000 |

My intent is to convert this to a temporal table, and then apply the updates in the order of my sort column.

So My Active will be:

| Key Value | Update Flag | Sort Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | Change | 04/01/2000 |

And my HIST table would be:

| Key Value | Update Flag | Sort Flag | SysStrtTime | SysEndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | Add | 01/01/2000 | ST1 | ST2 |
| X1 | Change | 02/01/2000 | ST2 | ST3 |
| X1 | Change | 03/01/2000 | ST4 | ST5 |

Where ST1-STN are just the system time at which the record is updated.

Comment: This is entirely too vague for anybody to have much input.

Comment: I've added some additional information. Does this help explain what I am trying to do?

Comment: I think perhaps you are confused about what a temporal table is. But I still don't really understand what you are asking here. No idea what "these updates" are or what it means to apply them.